# Cant find Qt5Core.lib

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

When building a project with

```
cmake .
```

the command

```
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
```

in the `CMakeLists` fails.
It throws

```
CMake Error at C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:14 (message):
  The imported target "Qt5::Core" references the file

     "C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/Qt5Core.lib"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.
```

as an error.
When searching for `Qt5Core.lib` through regular file explorer I can only find `Qt5Core.prl` and `Qt5Core.dll` but no `Qt5Core.lib`. How do I get `Qt5Core.lib`? Why doesn't it exist?

The code in `Qt5CoreConfig.cmake` in line 13 to 23:

```
if(NOT EXISTS "${file}" )
        message(FATAL_ERROR "The imported target \"Qt5::Core\" references the file
   \"${file}\"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}\"
but not all the files it references.
")
    endif()
```

Comment: "it says the file ..." - Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact** and **complete** error message. Also, files like `*Config.cmake` are not intended to be "executed" directly. You probably have a call like `find_package(Qt5Core)` in your CMake project.

Comment: this file (Qt5Core.lib) does no exist because you did not check QT5 in the QT maintenance tool. Maybe you installed `Qt6`? check if you have `Qt6Core.lib` to verify if it's an installation issue.